# VBA word Macro not working across different computers

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I put together a simple macro to find instances of text within brackets and highlighting everything within the brackets, though for some reason it doesn't work on another computer:

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\[texthere*\]"
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 16
    .Replacement.Text = "^13 ^&"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
```

I have isolated the problem on the non-working computer to a failure to recognize the search string `"/[texthere*/]"`, because if I removed the backslash and brackets and simply search for "texthere*", the highlighting action works.

First I checked security settings and they are the same on both machines. Next I checked versions and libraries. The working machine is 14.4.1 and the non-working version is 14.4.7, which from the looks of it is kind of buggy--I searched exhaustively online for an answer and found people talking about problems with 'Form Controls' in Excel which have resulted from the 14.4.7 update, but I don't know what could be causing the problem in Word.

Is it possible that the update is making it so that my `Selection.find.Text` string can't be found?
The libraries seem to be the same, but I didn't know if there was a way to fix the problem by adding to the library?
Anyway, how do I get it to work on the other computer too?

Comment: The library update could be the issue. Certainly.

Answer (score 1):

Find settings can persist from previous uses, so it's possible the non-working computer has a different default applied. Try for example explicitly setting the MatchWildcards value instead of relying on the existing value.

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchWildcards = True    '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    .Text = "\[texthere*\]"
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 16
    .Replacement.Text = "^13 ^&"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
```